# How to check if a given ID is for a product variation? woocoomerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have an array full of produtcs SKU's that i search for the ID.

```
$ID = wc_get_product_id_by_sku($CodProduto);
```

then i initialize the object and set the stock for the current amount.

```
$Product = new WC_Product( $ID);
$return = wc_update_product_stock( $Product, $Stock);
```

So far so good! All works fine. My problem is when the `$ID` is for a product variation it wont initialize the object and will give an error. So i initialize all ID's with:

```
$Product = new WC_Product_Variation( $ID );
```

And then i update the stock like i did before.
The problem is that when a product DONT have variation, the woocommerce puts the Name as (no title) but the stock works fine.

Is there a way to check if the ID is for a variation without initialize the object $Product???
[image]

Comment: You want to check the product on single page, archive page ?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the product by using wc_get_product().

```
$product = wc_get_product($ID);

if( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ){
    // simple product
} elseif( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ){
   // variable product
}
```

This way you will always get the correct product class simple/variation.

Comment: I think there should be another ELSE at the end with NULL value. Not 100% sure through.

Comment: Doesnt work, i said that if you do  ````$product = wc_get_product($ID);```` and the $ID is for a variation it will give a fatal error. I already did this by using try catch, ill post it when i can.

Comment: @AlexisGarcia this is a tested code, perhaps errorlog the ID and check if these ids are valid variations or simple products.

Comment: I tested it to, it gives me a fatal error, thats why i was asking for help. If you read my code, i already do that with simple products.

Comment: You will need to share the error from the log with us :)

Answer (score 3):

You can check if product is variation with get_parent_id(), if it is a variation you will get the parent id, if not you will get zero. i.e.

```
$product=wc_get_product($product_id);
$product_parent=$product->get_parent_id();

if($product_parent==0){
//what you want to do with non product that is not a variation
}else{
//what you want to do with product variation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use another method by searching in database

For example, if not sure whether this ID is for Product or Variation Product, you can use:

`( get_post( not_sure_ID ) )->post_parent;`

As a child post (Variation Product) , its parent value will not be 0. On the other hand is 0 (Product).

or

`( get_post( not_sure_ID ) )->post_type;`

If this ID is for Variation Product, return value should be **product_variation**

Answer (score 1):

If you feed the ID into get_post_type() it should return with either 'product' or 'product_variation'. This worked for me.

```
$post_type = get_post_type($ID);

if( $post_type == 'product' ){
    // product
} elseif( $post_type == 'product_variation' ){
   // product variation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    // Check if it's product or variation
    if (is_a($product, 'WC_Product_Variation')) {
        $product_id = $product->get_parent_id();
    }
```

Better to check if it's actually a variation.